# Part random retrieval, part minimize repeats

Tags: javascript, algorithm, random

I have an array of 10 numbers:

```
var array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
```

I've written a function (below) to return a random element from the array without repeating a return of the same element until 8 other elements have been returned.  It works but seems very inefficient because the random number generator will often need to be invoked many times before the code can continue.  Is there a more efficient way to accomplish the same result?

```
var array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
var recentlyReturned = [];

function minimalRepeat() {

var i = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
while( recentlyReturned.indexOf(i) != -1 ) {
    i = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
}

recentlyReturned.push(i);
while(recentlyReturned.length>8) {
    recentlyReturned.shift();
}
return array[i];
}


for(var i=1; i<20; i++) {
    console.log(minimalRepeat());
}
```

*** Edit ***

I rewrote the code based on feedback from Tudor Ilisoi.  It's definitely more efficient.  However, it's possible to get repeats across shuffle boundaries.

Version 2:

```
function shuffle(arr) {
    var copyArr = arr.slice();
    for (let i = copyArr.length; i; i--) {
        let j = Math.floor(Math.random() * i);
        [copyArr[i - 1], copyArr[j]] = [copyArr[j], copyArr[i - 1]];
    }
    return copyArr;
}

var a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
var b = shuffle(a);

for(var i=1; i<20; i++) {
    if(b.length == 0) {
        b = shuffle(a);
    }
    console.log(b.pop());
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fisher-Yates:

```
function shuffle(array) {
  var m = array.length, t, i;

  while (m) {

    i = Math.floor(Math.random() * m--);

    t = array[m];
    array[m] = array[i];
    array[i] = t;
  }

  return array;
}

var origArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
var numbers = origArray;
var randomNumbers = shuffle(numbers);

var result = randomNumbers.slice(0, 8);

for (var i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
  result.push(randomNumbers[Math.floor(Math.random() * (origArray.length-1))]);
}
```

First 8 numbers should be unique (from the predined set).
Next 11 numbers can be duplicates within the selected numbers and from the predefined set.

(If I understand the question correctly.)

**Edit based on comments**

Since the *no-repeat-window* is eight you're left with two numbers from the array; The last two numbers.

The next random number is the first number in the array.

What you can do is `pop` and `shift` these numbers into a temporary array, shuffle the temporary array and `push` the temporary array back to the random array.

```
var origArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
var randomNumbers = shuffle(origArray);

for (var i = 0; i < 19; i++)
{
    var tmp = [];
    tmp.push(randomNumbers.pop());   // First number not in no-repeat-window
    tmp.push(randomNumbers.pop());   // Second number not in no-repeat-window
    tmp.push(randomNumbers.shift()); // Current random number.

    randomNumbers.push.apply(randomNumbers, shuffle(tmp));
}
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/j7yjqpkz/)

Comment: I should have been more clear in my question.  Perhaps a better way to say it is that at all times the most recent 8 items returned cannot repeat.

Comment: @Timothy Seevers So for i-th returned item there is choice only between [i-9]-th and [i-10]th items?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.  Hence, the inefficiency of generating random numbers till the ninth or tenth item is selected.  But that makes me think that I could randomly select between the 2 remaining numbers only and not the entire set.  I think that would work.  I'll have to try it to verify.

Comment: @TimothySeevers: You can randomly select between the two remaining numbers *and* the current random number (first in the array). See my edit.

Comment: Yes, this works and avoids try till you don't fail.  Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

- make a copy of the array and randomize it in place. let's call it `copy`
- your minimalRepeat will extract from the randomized copy with `copy.pop()` until the copy is empty(or 8 elements were extracted). When this condition is met, make another copy

By extracting from the randomized copy you're making sure you will not return the same element until the copy is generated again.

**Edit based on comment feedback**

```js
function shuffle(arr) {
  var copyArr = arr.slice();
  for (let i = copyArr.length; i; i--) {
    let j = Math.floor(Math.random() * i);
    [copyArr[i - 1], copyArr[j]] = [copyArr[j], copyArr[i - 1]];
  }
  return copyArr;
}

var latest = []
var a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
var b = shuffle(a);

for (var i = 1; i < 20; i++) {
  if (b.length == 0) {
    b = shuffle(a);
  }
  var popped = b.pop()

  //if found in recents
  if (latest.indexOf(popped) !== -1) {
    continue;
  }

  //push the popped element
  latest.push(popped)
  if (latest.length > 8) {
    latest.shift() //remove the oldest "recent" to keep the "latest" length at 8
  }

  console.log(popped);
}
```

Comment: Ah, that does make sense.  I'll try rewriting my code based on your suggestion and post the result.

Comment: I did write the code to shuffle the array until empty and shuffle again when empty.  I'll edit my post to share it.  It's definitely more efficient, however, it's possible to get repeats as you cross from one shuffled set to the next.  The worst case example is that on shuffle copy 1, the last item in the stack ends up as the first item in the stack for shuffle copy 2.

Comment: indeed... you need to do one more thing. keep in another array the latest 8 extracted, and if the element you just popped is there, `pop()` another one. The original array must be larger than 8, otherwise you get an infinite loop

Comment: edited, seems to work now. I now see that you have the latest/recentlyReturned code in the initial question. Anyway, it works.

Comment: This does work and is better than my original.  But, I was trying to avoid the try till you don't fail scenario.

Answer (score 0):

You can organize cyclic queue in array:

```
Randomize array A[] with Fisher-Yates algo
Set Idx to 0
At every step generate random r = 0 or 1 
If r=1 swap A[Idx % 10] and A[(Idx + 1) % 10]
Output A[Idx % 10] 
Increment Idx
```